# Using `say` to read terminal output from a command line tool?

Tags: terminal

I'm not sure if this is possible. I'm using a command line log parser for an MMO I play. Information is shown in Terminal window but I have to read it while playing rather than hear it while playing. I'd like to program Terminal to **say** the output as it's being streamed to the screen.

I'm new to the command line and Terminal-- is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
<command> 2>&1 | while read line ; do echo $line | say ; done
```

<sup>Replace `<command>` with the normal command that outputs what you would like to be spoken.</sup>

Comment: You may want to pipe it to a `say` + `sleep` function so there's a slight pause between reading each line.